# Systematically transform a multivariate function into several univariate functions

Tags: r, function

Let's say I have a function of two parameters:

> `foo <- function(mu,sigma){
>     return(dnorm(x=0, mean=mu, sd=sqrt(sigma)))
>     }`

I can turn this into two univariate functions:

> `foo.mu <- function(mu) foo(mu,sigma=sigma.init)`
>
> `foo.sigma <- function(sigma) foo(mu=mu.init, sigma)`

This is of course very straigtforward. But what if I have 200 variables? For example, if I have a function

> `foo2 <- function(mu){
>    ...
>   }`

where now `mu` is a vector of length, say, 200. Is there a way to systematically go through all 200 univariate functions obtained by fixing all coordinates except one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why you want this, and it's probably not the right approach, but what you're asking for can be done:

```
# example 10-parameter mu
mu <- setNames(as.list(runif(10, 0, 1)), paste0('mu', seq_len(10)))
len <- length(mu)
# example 10-argument function
mufoo <- function() {}
body(mufoo) <- parse(text = paste(paste0("mu", seq_len(len)), collapse = " + "))
formals(mufoo) <- setNames(rep(list(formals(function(x){})[[1]]), len), paste0('mu', seq_len(len)))
print(mufoo)
# function (mu1, mu2, mu3, mu4, mu5, mu6, mu7, mu8, mu9, mu10)
#    mu1 + mu2 + mu3 + mu4 + mu5 + mu6 + mu7 + mu8 + mu9 + mu10

foos <- lapply(seq_along(mu), function(ix) {
  force(ix); force(mu)
  function(submu) {
    mu[[ix]] <- submu
    do.call(mufoo, mu)
  }
})
```

Now `foos` is a list of ten functions, each univariate and controlling exactly one of the 10 parameters in `mu`:

```
dput(as.numeric(mu))
# c(4.56169327721, 3.67214910686016, 3.32561796996742, 7.03987624496222,
# 4.30756138870493, 9.66635353863239, 4.04302914626896, 8.62502690404654,
# 1.0719409561716, 2.95157870510593)
foos[[5]](5)
# [1] 49.95727
foos[[6]](5)
# [1] 44.59847
```

You can even name them `foo1`, `foo2`, ...

```
for (ix in seq_along(foos)) assign(paste0('foo', ix), foos[[ix]], envir = environment())
foo1(5)
# [1] 49.70313
```